# Combining ListView.CheckedListViewItemCollections

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

I have several `ListView.CheckedListViewItemCollection` from different tabs on a form I have. Does anybody know the best way to combine all these instances of `ListView.CheckedListViewItemCollection` into some sort of single Collection/Array?

Answer (score 0):

[ListView.CheckedListViewItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkedlistviewitemcollection%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) supports the [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx) interface so you should be able use Linq to apply a [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) or [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) to your collections depending on your requirements.